# excel vba code to check for a folder if it exists, if not create a folder

Tags: excel, vba, macos, directory

I am a newbie in excel vba coding and trying to create pdf of a excel sheet range. My code works well in windows OS but somehow it doesn't work in Mac OS. The Code is as below:
`

```
Sub GeneratePDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim VelleName As String
Dim SelectedRange As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("modulo")
.Activate
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(33, 10)).Select
Selection.Name = "SelectedRange"
End With


On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("modulo")
strTime = Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

VelleName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database").Range("B" & Desiredrow) & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database").Range("C" & Desiredrow)

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(VelleName, " ", "_")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")
strName = Replace(strName, "-", "_")
strName = Replace(strName, "/", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"

strPathFile = strName & "_" & strTime


' select folder for file
If Dir(strPath & Application.PathSeparator & "forme", vbDirectory) = "" Then '<== check if folder exists but its not detecting even though i had created a folder there.
    MkDir (ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "forme") '<== Create Folder and its not working for Mac OS.
End If
myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "forme" & Application.PathSeparator & strPathFile


'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
With wsA.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PrintArea = "SelectedRange"
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
    
    MsgBox "Il file pdf è stato creato: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Impossibile creare il file pdf"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

`
I have tried searching a lot on internet but havent found any source which specifically teaches vba coding in Mac OS. Moreover, i got only one link https://macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/makefolder/ but i dont think it would work as it should be only one line of command and the biggest issue i dont have Mac OS available now. So can somebody test my code change my command to make it compatible it with Mac OS

Comment: Any Help is welcomed. If somebody gives me source link where i can learn vba for MacOS. It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error display do you encounter?

Comment: Its error in mkdir() line i have also commented that in code.

Comment: I know it is in mkdir() line but what error does it display when it runs on that line? Take a look at how vba is being sandboxed in MacOS  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this code and also add to check file exist

```
'Only Change code Here
Sub Verify()
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "C:\abc" '<--------This line
    If Not PathExist(myPath) Then MkDir (myPath)
End Sub

Private Function PathExist(path_ As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrNotExist
    Call ChDir(path_)
   PathExist = True
   Exit Function
ErrNotExist:
    PathExist = False
End Function

Private Function FileExist(filePath_ As String) As Boolean
    FileExist = Len(Dir(filePath_)) <> 0
End Function
```